# sed deletes differing portions of text

Tags: regex, text, sed, escaping

I am trying to manipulate a vocabulary list which is in ZDT format, that is: `Traditional Characters \t Simplified Characters \t Pinyin \t English \n`. I want to get rid of the Traditional Characters at the beginning of the line, so I tried to delete them with `sed 's/^[^\t]*\t//g' input.txt > output.txt` yet this gets me nowhere near my desired result, as in some lines everything up to somewhere in the English section is deleted and in other lines nothing at all is deleted and I cannot make out a pattern.

I think that the RegEx is correct, as I’ve tested it [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and Sublime Text 2 also works with it as expected. What is the problem here?

Edit:
Beginning of `input.txt` http://pastebin.com/fRemVPyT
Beginning of `output.txt` http://pastebin.com/EJkszFNF

Comment: That `sed` command seems fine for me (`/g` flag is useless). Can you provide some input data that doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: @Birei I added an example of what sed yields.

Comment: It works for me. Note that yours doesn't detect tabs and deletes until  it finds a literal `t` character. Maybe a `shell` problem, an old `sed` version or something like that. Try escaping it twice `\\t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all `sed` version likes `\t`. Try to use a literal tab character. You can create a `bash` variable containing a tab like this:

```
export TAB=$'\t'
```

Maybe like this:

```
sed "s/^[^$TAB]*$TAB//g" input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: It seems to be an OS X problem http://nixtricks.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/sed-replace-a-tab-character-using-sed/. I actually solved it by inputting the tab literally with `ctrl-v` followed by `tab`.